# Ramda - How to filter array with other array and multiple properties

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to filter one array with another array using Ramda.

This is an array of edges for ELK algorithm. `sources` and `targets` are arrays but in this case, those arrays have always single value.

```
const edges = [
    {
        "id": "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada#2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18",
        "sources": [
            "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada"
        ],
        "targets": [
            "2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada#7cf88eab-5da4-492b-839c-30916fa98fb9",
        "sources": [
            "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada"
        ],
        "targets": [
            "7cf88eab-5da4-492b-839c-30916fa98fb9"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328#53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158",
        "sources": [
            "fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328"
        ],
        "targets": [
            "53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158"
        ]
    }
]
```

This is an example of a second array that I would like to use to filter values from the first one - `id` corresponds to the value in `sources` and `outgoingNodeId` corresponds to the value in `targets` from the first array.

```
const selectedNodes = [
    {
        "id": "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada",
        "outgoingNodeId": "2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18",
        "groupId": "27",
        "sectionId": "0e09e7dd-0f71-48a1-a843-36d8e85574b3"
    },
    {
        "id": "fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328",
        "outgoingNodeId": "53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158",
        "groupId": "27",
        "sectionId": "0e09e7dd-0f71-48a1-a843-36d8e85574b3"
    }
]
```

In this case, result should look like this:

```
const result = [
    {
        "id": "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada#2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18",
        "sources": [
            "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada"
        ],
        "targets": [
            "2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328#53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158",
        "sources": [
            "fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328"
        ],
        "targets": [
            "53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158"
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried few things but to be honest I don't have anything worth showing here.

My last try was around:

```
R.pipe(
  R.groupBy(R.prop('sources'))
)(edges)
```

And then filtering using `R.filter(R.compose(R.flip(R.contains)(selectedNodesIds), R.prop('id')))`

But I need to filter not only `sources` but also `targets`

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

**EDIT:**
**Another example for a different approach:**

```
const edges = [
    {
        "id": "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada#2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18",
        "sources": [
            "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada"
        ],
        "targets": [
            "2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada#7cf88eab-5da4-492b-839c-30916fa98fb9",
        "sources": [
            "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada"
        ],
        "targets": [
            "7cf88eab-5da4-492b-839c-30916fa98fb9"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328#53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158",
        "sources": [
            "fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328"
        ],
        "targets": [
            "53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158"
        ]
    },
    ...multipleObjectsHere
]
```

`selectedNodes` contains only one object:

```
const selectedNodes = [
    {
        "id": "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada",
        "outgoingNodeId": "2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18",
        "groupId": "27",
        "sectionId": "0e09e7dd-0f71-48a1-a843-36d8e85574b3"
    }
]
```

As a result, we get:

```
const result = [
    {
        "id": "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada#2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18",
        "sources": [
            "47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada"
        ],
        "targets": [
            "2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328#53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158",
        "sources": [
            "fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328"
        ],
        "targets": [
            "53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158"
        ]
    },
    ...multipleObjectsHere
]
```

To sum up, if something is not in `selectedNodes` we don't filter it out and leave it as a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `R.innerJoin` to create an intersection between 2 arrays using a comparison function:

```js
const { innerJoin, includes } = R

const fn = innerJoin(({ sources, targets }, { id, outgoingNodeId }) => 
  includes(id, sources) && includes(outgoingNodeId, targets)
)

const edges = [{"id":"47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada#2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18","sources":["47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada"],"targets":["2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18"]},{"id":"47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada#7cf88eab-5da4-492b-839c-30916fa98fb9","sources":["47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada"],"targets":["7cf88eab-5da4-492b-839c-30916fa98fb9"]},{"id":"fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328#53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158","sources":["fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328"],"targets":["53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158"]}]
const selectedNodes = [{"id":"47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada","outgoingNodeId":"2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18","groupId":"27","sectionId":"0e09e7dd-0f71-48a1-a843-36d8e85574b3"},{"id":"fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328","outgoingNodeId":"53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158","groupId":"27","sectionId":"0e09e7dd-0f71-48a1-a843-36d8e85574b3"}]

const result = fn(edges, selectedNodes)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

The other logic should be see if the `id` is included in sources. If it is also check the `outgoingNodeId`. If not, return `true`.

```js
const { innerJoin, includes } = R

const fn = innerJoin(({ sources, targets }, { id, outgoingNodeId }) => 
  !includes(id, sources) || includes(outgoingNodeId, targets)
)

const edges = [{"id":"47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada#2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18","sources":["47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada"],"targets":["2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18"]},{"id":"47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada#7cf88eab-5da4-492b-839c-30916fa98fb9","sources":["47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada"],"targets":["7cf88eab-5da4-492b-839c-30916fa98fb9"]},{"id":"fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328#53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158","sources":["fefd95e0-11d0-44f6-9b48-ec2a0ea1b328"],"targets":["53a6d558-c97b-42df-af69-cf27912dd158"]}]
const selectedNodes = [{"id":"47c0ffd2-6a2c-4e7f-9fd9-0e1207225ada","outgoingNodeId":"2789a940-15d1-4ff0-b2ef-9f6cde676c18","groupId":"27","sectionId":"0e09e7dd-0f71-48a1-a843-36d8e85574b3"}]

const result = fn(edges, selectedNodes)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Working as expected like always :) 
Can you help me with one adjustment? Because I tested it and apparently didn't think this through.
1. Filter out values with same `id` - `sources`, `outgoingNodeId` - `targets` exactly like right now
2. But leave all other values unfiltered. For example, if `selectedNodes` contains only one value we should filter only objects with the same `sources`, `targets` and leave all other values unfiltered and add them as part of result.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please add an example

Comment: I added another example. Hope it explains it better. Basically, if something is in `selectedNodes` we should filter it and leave the rest of `edges` untouched